# Android styling indeterminate progress bar

Tags: android, android-styles, android-progressbar

I'm trying to get this horizontal indeterminate progress bar (bottom) looking like the other (top, determinate) progress bars in my app:

[image]

I'm using the same style parent for each, but it shows a different progress background, and thickness.

My determinate progress bars are defined as:

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@style/MyProgressBarStyle" />
```

And my indeterminate horizontal prog bar:

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:indeterminateOnly="true"
    style="@style/MyProgressBarStyle" />
```

And MyProgressBarStyle:

```
<style name="MyProgressBarStyle"
    parent="Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal" />
```

So using the same style for each, why don't they have the same thickness and background? Is there a simple fix to make them look identical?

Comment: It's probably because one is indeterminate and one is not.

Comment: right but is it possible to style the indeterminate without redefining an entire list of animated drawables?